# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running Scala-Maven project

Tags: scala, maven, maven-3

Trying to run a new project for the first time. `mvn install` goes smoothly, but when I try to run it, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Tuple2
```

Now, something is terribly wrong if it can't even find the Scala basics. To be honest, it doesn't recognize anything outside of the code itself. 
I''m attaching my POM file, hope someone can help..

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Foo Bar</name>

  <properties>
    <app.main.class>com.foo.main</app.main.class>
    <spark.version>1.6.1</spark.version>
    <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
  </properties>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-repo</id>
      <name>Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>apache-repo</id>
      <name>Apache release repo</name>
      <url>https://github.com/adatao/mvnrepos/tree/master/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.foo.main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <jvmArgs>
            <jvmArg>-Xms256m</jvmArg>
            <jvmArg>-Xmx2048m</jvmArg>
          </jvmArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It's weird. Your pom works just fine for me.